# Connecting to API on Local Host - Android Emulator

Tags: android, api, android-emulator

I've tried connecting to an API running locally on my machine to retrieve values in an Android emulator.
I keep getting 404 Error. Any idea what should be done here for the API?  Thank you for your help.

```
            var test = "";
            var url = "http://10.0.2.2:60002/api/values/" + Convert.ToInt32(Id);

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                        "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                               $"{user}:{pass}")));
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                test = response;
            }
            return test;
```

Comment: Localhost is the emulator when an app on the emulator uses it. Every device is its own localhost. Please rephrase your post and tell what you want.

Comment: `var url = "http://10.0.2.2:60002/api/values/....` Yes! If that url is used by an app running on an emulator it tries to connect with a server running on the same pc as the emulator is running on.

Comment: If you know what 404 means then you know also that a connection has been established as this error code is send by the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

use 127.0.0.1 as the ip address. It should solve the problem.
If not,
type "**adb shell ifconfig**" or "**adb shell ipaddr**" in your command prompt.
(once of them should work)
Check if your either one of your machine's ip adresses are there. If there is a matching one use it.
To check your machine's ipaddress,

- If you are using windows
  Type **ipconfig** in your command prompt.
- If you are using Linux
  Type **ifconfig** in your shell.